# Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase' and 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

Xcode>Runner.xcodeproj>Product>Archive i get these errors when I do:

- Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'
- No such module 'Flutter'
- 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found

Note1 = VS Code the application opens

Answer (score 3):

If you have in your podfile:

> platform :ios, '11.0'

Then in XCode "Build Settings" you also have to choose

> iOs Deployment Target: 11.0

Comment: This was the issue on my end. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the following commands ?

```
flutter pub get
cd ios
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock (to be sure)
pod install --repo-update
```

Please share full logs.

Comment: hi @Eng I followed what you said and I keep getting the same error.